# MySQL: update column "foo" when column "job_date" is older than 2015-01-01

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I update column "foo" in all records when column "job_date" is older than 2015-01-01?

Comment: Edit your question and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing anything else about your table schema...

```html
UPDATE table_name_goes_here
SET foo = some_value_goes_here
WHERE job_date < '2015-01-01'
```

Comment: should be less than since OLDER than